# Inserting table header with a directive

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm trying to insert a table header using an angular directive. However, instead of going inside the `thead` where it is desired, it instead is placed outside the `table` element.
Here's the codepen: http://codepen.io/sachingoel0101/pen/yYvmGV

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
    <thead>
        <sortingheader/>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

only becomes:

```
<tr>
    <th>Sushi Roll</th>
    <th>Fish type</th>
    <th>Taste Level</th>
</tr>
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
    <thead></thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

Here's the directive code:

```
.directive('sortingheader', function() {
    return {
        replace: true,
        template: "<tr><th>Sushi Roll</th><th>Fish type</th><th>Taste Level</th></tr>"
    }
})
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your directive `restrict` property to:

```
restrict:'A'
```

And at HTML:

```
<tr sortingheader></tr>
```

[Working solution](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vNdoqP)

Comment: Any particular reason a standalone element doesn't work here? I'm not using IE, which seemingly has some problems.

Comment: I do not know why, but I had the same problem.

Comment: The reason is that <thead><sortingheader/></thead> is invalid HTML so the browser moves it outside the table before Angular is involved at all. See <thead> docs here, "Permitted content: Zero or more <tr> elements." https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/thead